# How to install php java bridge on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: java, php, apache

tried to install php java bridge on Ubuntu 12.04 with Apache ,but no luck,can anyone please tell me the exact procedure or steps need to do the same.I tried the following steps and i received the error as follows:

Step 1) sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre sun-java6-fonts sun-java6-jdk sun-java6-plugin

Step 2)sudo apt-get install liblucene-java libitext-java(got error that unable to install liblucene-java)

Step 3)sudo dpkg -i /home/nileema/Desktop/php-java-bridge_4.3.0-1_i386.deb

Step 4)sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart